# Skip non empty cells to paste special data

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to copy data from range (a3:M3) in worksheet "SL" to range (a3:m3) in worksheet "EL" only if range (a3:M3) is empty. Else to copy the selected data to the next row (a4:m4).

Below is the code i tried to work out ..but its not working...plz help

```
Range("C9:G10").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("EL").Select

For n = 1 To n = 100
    If Cells(n, 2).Value <> "" Then 
        Cells(n + 1, 2).Select
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next n
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some points in your code I do not understand:

- why does it refer to `C9:G10`?
- Why is there a loop from `n=1 to 100`?
- The syntax `For n = 1 To n = 100` does not work as you might expect -> replace it with `For n = 1 To 100`.)

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
Sub copyRange()

    ' Look if destination cells are empty

    Dim isempty As Boolean    
    isempty = True

    For Each cell In Sheets("EL").Range("a3:m3").Cells
        If cell.Value! = "" Then isempty = False
    Next

    ' Copy content from SL to EL into the correct line
    Sheets("SL").Range("a3:m3").Select
    Selection.Copy
    If isempty Then
        Sheets("EL").Range("a3:m3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    Else
        Sheets("EL").Range("a4:m4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Howard!C9:G10 is just the initial data to be copied (for ease of reference i put a3:m3) well sorry for not being clear initially in my question. actually it should be continuous. That is if a3:m3 is not empty then should go to a4:m4, if a4:m4 is not empty, then a5:m5 and continue till last cell in excel or limit it say to a10000:m10000